# How to mass upload PDF files and save into MySQL using Servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, file-upload

How do I mass upload PDF files or a folder with PDF files and save it into my MySQL database using Servlet?

Comment: what is the rational upload PDF to mysql database ? OR you mean extract the PDF and stored into database ?

Comment: @ajreal.... i meant it should only fetch the pdf files which is stored in the folder...and should be able to fetched to database

Comment: @dude - Make it clearer at your question. Again, what does fetch to database mean? And what does it to do with mysql ?

Comment: @ajreal: fetch means its should automatically only select the pdf files n store it to the database when i upload through servlet???

Comment: @dude - Should not you use a better description?, like `how to ensure uploaded pdf files save into mysql using servlet`?

Comment: @ajreal...sure mate... from now on i wil give a better description :)

Answer (score 1):

The best you do is to ask user to specify the files using several `<input type="file"...>` elements on the page. And on submit check if all the files are PDF or not, perform desired action in either case. Or you can check for the PDF extension right away using JavaScript. You can also validate using AJAX, just send an AJAX request to the server on a `onBlur` event of the `input field`.

Otherwise, a privileged applet might be able to help a little more than this. For example asking a directory and scanning for all PDF's etc.